# Vampire romance series

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, vampire, psychic, shape-shifter

There's this vampire romance series. In the first book, the male lead (Kaden, I think is his name) kidnaps a human woman and her psychic daughter. The lady also has a sister, Emma, who is in hiding.
Kaden (?) has a couple of brothers, I think. They all live in a compound. 
There are also shifters in the story. Oh, and the FBI knows about the vampires existence.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [*Fated*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8686057-fated) by Rebecca Zanetti? The main character (Cara) has a sister (Emma) and a psychic daughter (Janie). She comes into contact with the main vampire character (Talen, not Kaden) quite early on in the book.

> **Marry Me!** Cara Paulsen does not give up easily. A scientist and a single mother, she's used to fighting for what she wants, keeping a cool head, and doing whatever it takes to protect her daughter Janie. But "whatever it takes" has never before included a shotgun wedding to a dangerous-looking stranger with an attitude problem.
>
> **Or Else!** Sure, the mysterious Talen says that he's there to protect Cara and Janie. He also says that he's a three-hundred-year-old vampire. Of course, the way he touches her, Cara might actually believe he's had that long to practice. . .

[image]